# Add and Remove plots to a matplotlib figure

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have an interface developed with PyQt5 with 4 buttons (2 add buttons and 2 remove buttons). I can plot the first dataset but when I plot the second dataset, the first dataset is erased. The idea is to have the possibility to add or remove datasets just by clicking buttons. Here the initial code:

```
class Mainwindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)        
        self.btn_add_1.clicked.connect(self.add_1)
        self.btn_add_2.clicked.connect(self.add_2)
        self.btn_remove_1.clicked.connect(self.remove_1)
        self.btn_remove_2.clicked.connect(self.remove_2)

    def add_1(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.y = [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.add_selected = 'add_1'
        self.Graphique = Graphique(self.add_selected, self.x, self.y, self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graphique, 0, 0, 1, 1)     

    def add_2(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.y = [1,4,6,8,10]
        self.add_selected = 'add_2'
        self.Graphique = Graphique(self.add_selected, self.x, self.y, self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graphique, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    def remove_1(self):
        pass

    def remove_2(self):
        pass

class Graphique(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, add_selected, x, y, parent =None):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.add_selected = add_selected

        self.fig = Figure()        
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)   
        self.Populate()

    def Populate(self):
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)           
        lines = self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y,'o-')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Mainwindow()   
    prog.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Currently each dataset has its own figure. Instead you would want to create one figure and let only the data change, not the complete figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure

import random


class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs   = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys   = list(line.get_ydata())

        self.btnAdd = QPushButton("add datasets just by clicking buttons")
        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.btnClick)

    def btnClick(self):
#        self.x = [1,2,3,4,5]
#        self.y = [1,2,3,4,5]  
        self.x = random.sample(range(100), 5) 
        self.y = random.sample(range(100), 5)        

        self.xs.append(self.x)
        self.ys.append(self.y)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()
#        print(f" \n xs={self.xs}, \n ys={self.ys}")



class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):                      #, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mainwindow, self).__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.set_title('Click to add a dataset')
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [], 'o-')                              
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)        

        self.ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 100])

        self.LineBuilder = LineBuilder(self.line)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.LineBuilder.btnAdd, 2, 0, 1, 1)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = Mainwindow()   
    prog.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it almost answers to my problem. I need to plot on the same figure a scatterplot and a regular plot (the regular plot could be removed by clicking another button). I tried your approach by adding the following code: `self.heat = self.ax.scatter([], [], marker='o')` and `self.heat.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)` but I got this error `AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'set_data'`